# How can I define ε when I'm writing the grammar rules in parsing code?

Tags: python, yacc, lex, context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I'm trying to write a compiler program for a specific grammar I defined.

There are a few **ε** in the grammar because of some iterative and recursive rules. I tried to define **ε** by creating an empty token:

```
tokens = (
    'EMPTY'
) 

t_EMPTY = r'\ '
```

That caused some parsing problems, therefore I ignored spaces earlier in the lexer code:

```
t_ignore  = ' \t'
```

What are other ways to describe define **ε**?

Click [here](https://github.com/euleriscoding/A-Parsing-Trial/tree/main) to see the project files

Comment: Reading [yacc.py](https://github.com/euleriscoding/A-Parsing-Trial/blob/main/yacc.py#L1812), it appears to use a special value, `'<empty>'`, to represent the empty terminal. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.The yacc.py module I used includes a special `<empty>` value for **ε**. Here is empty defining in the grammar part of the code:

```
def p_empty(p):
    'empty :'
    pass

def p_option(p):
    '''option : start 
              | empty '''
```